# Solving coupled pde

Tags: differential-equations

I am new to Mathematica and I want to solve this coupled pde
I used this `DSolve` but it did not work. I am not sure what I did wrong.

[image]

This is how I used `DSolve`

[image]

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Please add the code that you ran (rather than a screenshot) to the question so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`InputForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html) when providing input to the notebook and you will be less likely to make mistakes. Also, when posting to this site, convert any code to `InputForm` and copy and paste the code (as a code block) rather than a picture of the code.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {w D[c[x, t], t] + u D[c[x, t], x] - 
     v  D[c[x, t], {x, 2}] == - k c[x, t] s[x, t], 
   D[s[x, t], t] == -p k c[x, t] s[x, t]};

sol = DSolve[eqns, {c, s}, {x, t}]

(* {{c -> Function[{x, t}, -(1/(k p w))
     2 C[1] (u - 2 v C[1]) (-1 + 
        Tanh[x C[1] - (t C[1] (u - 2 v C[1]))/w + C[3]])], 
  s -> Function[{x, t}, (
    2 v C[1]^2 (1 + Tanh[x C[1] - (t C[1] (u - 2 v C[1]))/w + C[3]])^2)/
    k]}, {c -> 
   Function[{x, t}, -(1/(k p w))
     2 C[1] (u + 2 v C[1]) (1 + 
        Tanh[x C[1] - (t C[1] (u + 2 v C[1]))/w + C[3]])], 
  s -> Function[{x, t}, (
    2 v C[1]^2 (-1 + Tanh[x C[1] - (t C[1] (u + 2 v C[1]))/w + C[3]])^2)/
    k]}, {c -> 
   Function[{x, t}, (2 C[2] Tanh[t C[2] - (w x C[2])/u + C[3]])/(k p)], 
  s -> Function[{x, t}, (1/(k u^2))
    2 v w^2 C[
      2]^2 (-1 + Tanh[t C[2] - (w x C[2])/u + C[3]]) (1 + 
       Tanh[t C[2] - (w x C[2])/u + C[3]])]}} *)
```

where the `C[i]` are arbitrary constants.

Verifying that the solutions satisfy the equations

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {{True, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}} *)
```

Comment: thank you so much now if i want to add so
me initial conditions, how can i do it 

  c(0, t) = cd(t), for t in [0,T],
c(L, t) = 0, for t in [0,T],
c(x,0) = 0, for x in [0,L],
s(x,0) = s0, for x in [0,L].

Comment: Add them to the `eqns`. See the documentation for `DSolve`

Comment: can you please show me how to plot them i need to see the graphe

Comment: Assign values to constants/parameters and see documentation for Plot3D. If you have questions, show the code for what you have tried, state what problems you are having, and what error messages you are receiving.